# Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_get_current_user()

Tags: wordpress

I'm getting the above error on my Wordpress Multisite only when clicking through to 'Network Admin' '/wp-admin/network' - this doesn't happen on the other sub-domains.

I've tried adding this code

```
if(!function_exists('wp_get_current_user')) {
include(ABSPATH . "wp-includes/pluggable.php"); }
```

and also this

```
( ABSPATH . '/wp-includes/pluggable.php' ); $user_info = wp_get_current_user();
```

but to no avail. All I've been trying to do is install a new theme and work on it, this bit has been successful. The problems I'm incurring shouldn't have happened surely.

I've completely removed the old theme too. I'm out of ideas. I've been googling most of the morning and night too.

What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You should not call that function directly, but you need to use WP functions inside action and filter hooks.

F.e.

```
add_action('init', function(){

  $user_info = wp_get_current_user();

});
```

Comment: do I add this to capabilites.php?

Comment: functions.php -

Comment: never edit any file inside wp-admin and wp-includes. Your code area is wp-content/themes and wp-content/plugins dir-s

Comment: So to confirm, I add the above code from Elvin in to the functions.php file? Not capabilities or pluggable?

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. I tried adding the above code from Elvin Haci on to functions.php and I'm still returning the same error.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_get_current_user() in /home2/tmr2709/public_html/wp-includes/capabilities.php on line 619

Comment: probably because you still have the old pieces of code you added? Maybe take those out and leave only what @ElvinHaci provided?

Comment: I removed all the modifications to the code, added the above code to functions.php inside wp-content/themes and I'm still getting the error message. Removed the theme and manually uploaded it via FTP - same error.

Restored old theme, same error.

Looked on Wordpress Codex, tried the suggestions there. Nope, same error.

I've never come across this error before, and I'm relunctant to, but would probably consider reinstalling WP Multi-site again and start from scratch as I can't figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

You may add the following:

```
require_once('pluggable.php');
```

at the top of file `wp-includes/capabilities.php`

It worked with me. [referrence of the solution](https://buddypress.org/support/topic/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-wp_get_current_user/#post-37054)

**PS: I'm not sure if it's the best solution.**

Comment: No it's not. You should use hook instead.

Answer (score -1):

After much googling and asking plenty of questions and finding different answers, I found my issue and it was conflicting plugin to do with theme that I installed. Thanks for your help and coding solutions.

Comment: You need to add more details for this to be an answer. Answers are meant to be useful to other people experiencing similar problems to help them solve them, e.g. which plugin and theme, and which parts of the code, conflicted?